# Why define method is missing in ExtJS 3.4.0?

Tags: extjs

In [ExtJS 3.4.0 API](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext), on the Ext singelton, is says that there's a 'define' method that one uses to define a Class. It is also noted that this is new since ExtJS 3.

From some reason, this method does not exists, and I wonder if anyone knows why?

You can see for you self by surfing to the Basic Grid example [page](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.4.0/examples/grid/array-grid.html), loading Developer Tools or Firebug, and on the Console write "Ext.define" which yields undefined.

Comment: Please post some code and exact error message you're getting

Comment: The code is the link hyperlinked on the "page" word. The check: "Ext.define" which can be run using Developer Tools (Chrome, Safari, etc), which returns undefined, and not a function as expected

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shorter, and probably the most accurated, answer is because the documentation is wrong. Extjs 3.4 doesn´t have an Ext.define method.

Answer (score 1):

Ext.define was added to the commercial version of ext released  July 30 2012. as of now only support customers have access to this release. [see release announcement](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?234266)